# Enter trade when price close above 20 + 200 EMA, close when price close below 20 EMA or close above bb high

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The script is working but not exactly as I want. So these are the trade conditions.

Entry: Price close above 20 EMA as well as 200 EMA.

Exit: Either price close below 20 EMA or price close above bollinger band high.

This is my code.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Script", overlay = true, calc_on_every_tick=true, process_orders_on_close = true)

ema20Close = ta.ema(close, 20)
ema200Close = ta.ema(close, 200)

bblength = input.int(20, minval=1)
bbsrc = input(close, title="Source")
bbmult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
bbbasis = ta.sma(bbsrc, bblength)
bbdev = bbmult * ta.stdev(bbsrc, bblength)
bbupper = bbbasis + bbdev
bblower = bbbasis - bbdev

entryCondition = close > ema20Close and close > ema200Close
closeCondition = close < ema20Close or close > bbupper

if ( entryCondition )
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if ( closeCondition )
    strategy.close("Long")

plot(ema20Close, color = color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth = 1)
plot(ema200Close, color = color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth = 1)
```

When price close above bollinger band high, system exits from the trade but the problem is, it again enters in the next candle because price is already above 20 EMA and 200 EMA. Which is not I want. I want the system to not take any more trade unless price again goes below any of the 20 EMA or 200 EMA and then satisfies entry conditions again.

I am really stuck here. Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ta.crossover()` function will return `true` only on the first bar where there is a crossover. For example, this code will return `true` only when `close` will crossover `ema200Close`:

```
ta.crossover(close, ema200Close)
```

Here is an example of how you can use it in your own code:

```
entryCondition = (close > ema20Close and ta.crossover(close, ema200Close)) or (close > ema200Close and ta.crossover(close, ema20Close))
```

Comment: Thank you. This check worked great. Although I think we should always be checking crossover with 20 EMA because it will be higher than 200 EMA for this setup and entry. No?

Comment: Hi. No. EMA 20 is not always higher than EMA 200 (otherwise they would never cross)